# SCardListReaders : Cannot find a smart card reader. (0x8010002E)

Tags: linux, smartcard

My local pc is intel_x86 run on Ubuntu linux

I'm trying to use a smartcard reader that I bought from China. The device is a Zoweetek zw-12026-3. I tried to install the driver from this link https://zoweetek.cn/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/9540-V2.zip there are a basic driver installation such as (pcsc-lite,libusb,ccid) I followed the installation guide and I had to run "sudo ./pcsc_demo" in "pcsc-lite-1.7.4/doc/example" and it was an error like this: [image] . I tried to restart pcscd and nothing change.

I have no exeperience before about using smartcard reader on linux or any device and there is a few information about it so if you don't mind please drop keywords or links
to let me study more.

Comment: I have seen about something like authentication in <https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-smart-cards> but I'm not sure what it is. Do I have to authenticate stuff? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: See: [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) for various smart cards. It is also available in most distros. [Ubuntu]( https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=opensc)